# Skype does not show video from my webcam

Tags: windows-7, video, skype, webcam

I have a webcam that works fine with other webcam software, like Yawcam or Webcamoid.

Today I installed the latest version of Skype. When I open Settings --> Audio & Video, it shows that the camera is detected correctly, but instead of the video I can only see a black screen. Audio works fine. There are no webcam settings that I can change in Skype. I tired to restart program many times. A couple of times it did show the video from the camera, but most of the other times it did not. I can not understand how to get it working. Is it blocked by an antivirus software? Then why other programs are not blocked from using the webcam?

In the Device Manager I can see the USB PC Camera, and it shows that the device is working properly. Skype Status does not detect any issues either.

I have a Windows 7 (x64) desktop.

How can I troubleshoot this?